# Multiple browsers failing on certain web pages

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge, brave

Suddenly multiple browsers are failing to load certain pages (consistently). Brave is showing an Aw, Snap error. Edge is showing a similar error. Internet Explorer seems ok, as does Firefox.

Pages that don't load include things like:
Gmail works, until I click to one of the other non-default tabs in my inbox
Brave.com 
Certain ://settings pages and the bookmarks page. Certain Amazon pages (not the homepage). It feels like most pages after you start clicking around. Very unusable.

I'm at a loss. I feel like there must be some underlying driver or something that multiple browsers rely on, but am not sure what that can be.

Tried reinstalling, restarting, clearing cache and all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Run TCP/IP Reset and DNS Flush:

1. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
2. Then: `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt`
3. Then: `ipconfig /flushdns`
4. Then: restart the computer

### Test after restarting the computer

If these steps fail, open an Admin command prompt and run DISM (`dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`)  followed by `SFC /SCANNOW` .

Failure of the above means a Windows 10 repair install

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Use the Upgrade Button, watch and be sure to Keep Everything.

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately that didn't fix it. What are you thinking might be wrong?

Comment: Another admin command prompt:  Run:  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  .  Follow with SFC /SCANNOW  .  After completion, restart and test.  These two commands fix a number of issues.  If these fail, make a new, test Windows User Account (Start, Settings, Accounts).  Log into the new account and test the browsing again.

Comment: Uh oh - looks like we got bigger problems. DISM failed at 8.2% with: The WOF driver encountered a corruption in the compressed file's Resource Table.

Comment: You need to run a Windows 10 Repair Install. Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 and click on the upgrade button. Watch it and select the default option to keep everything. Allow it to complete (about 90 minutes total), restart and test again

Comment: Looks like that worked. Appreciate your help! Any idea as to how it may have been caused (so I prevent it from happening again)?

Comment: It is hard to say what caused it so also how to prevent. I will adjust my answer to include the points and hopefully you will be able to accept it.