# Some web pages display massive icons?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I recently have started noticing that a few web pages, that work on other machines on the same network with the same virus protection, don't work on my Windows 10 machine. They load, and the links are all there, but the layout of the page is messed up. The icons for Twitter, Facebook, etc. are all massive, taking up more than a full screen and having to scroll for a bit just to get passed one icon.

I tried doing a uninstall reinstall of chrome, and have restarted multiple times.

I did recently start messing around with web development, and django.

Maybe I messed something up?

I tried both chrome and edge, and it is the exact same problem in both.

I tried solutions from here:

[Multiple browsers failing on certain web pages](https://superuser.com/questions/1508279/multiple-browsers-failing-on-certain-web-pages)

but nothing worked.

Edit: Forgot to add: Most websites work great. It is only a select few that have this issue. But I know these work on our network, and on other machines with the same virus protection and everything because I had a couple different co-workers try the site on their machine and it worked.

I have also tried clearing the Cache and Deleting the cookies.

I should also add, SFC /SCANNOW did find corrupt files and repaired them. But it did not fix the problem.

EDIT 2: Added a picture. [image] The website in particular that is not working for me is tera-digital.com but there are other websites not working as well.

Comment: Without providing a link or even a screenshot, this question cannot be answered. If it affects multiple browsers, it’s most likely nothing on your side.

Comment: Sounds like you might have some sites blocked from a firewall, possibly blocking the style sheets which are used in the site. Many sites use CDNs to distribute resources, and those can get blocked sometimes.

Comment: Added a picture, and the name of a website that is not working. Although, the website will work on your end probably. And the screenshot is not very helpful, because of the size of the icons, you can barely tell what is going on. That was why I initially didn't include it.

Comment: @LarryBud That could be the case, but it seems unlikely, as we are all on the same network and network firewall, and my co-workers are able to access the site without any problems.

Comment: It does appear that the CSS styling isn't being applied properly. Have you verified that java is properly installed and running too? Many sites use javascripts with CSS for styling as well. Doing an inspect on the page from Chrome shows many .js modules in the header

Comment: @EricF Java and Javascript are completely unrelated, name similarity is some marketing crap. You don't have to have Java installed for Javascript to work. JS runtimes are built into web browsers.

Comment: I have seen this behavior myself.  Are either of the machines connected to a proxy?  The basic explanation is that content is indeed being blocked

Comment: If you hit F12 to go to the Chrome dev tools and look at the "network" tab, you can see what isn't being loaded. From there you can try to open that single URL (e.g. a link to a CSS) and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the CSS file didn't load properly. Specifically, the file located at https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0144/3482/8374/t/4/assets/theme.scss.css?v=18162579756883198765 (it can be slightly different for different visitors). I've simulated blocking this file with Firefox's inspector and the website looked like this:

[image: Broken website screenshot]

It's being blocked on your computer for some reason. Probably the entire `cdn.shopify.com` host is banned. Some places to check:

- Ad blocking extensions. This can be a false positive. Not very likely because it happens in multiple browsers, but maybe you have the same adblock extension installed in all of them?
- Website blocking, parental controls software. It can be used to block hosts.
- `hosts` file. On Windows it's located in `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Editing it requires administrator privileges, but you should be able to open it with Notepad without them. It's sometimes used for system-wide host blocking.
- Router's website blacklist/parental controls.
- DNS settings. If you're using Pi-hole or some other privacy-oriented DNS, it can block some hosts too.